# Given a DAG, remove nodes exclusively present in paths shorter than length 3

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm, networkx, graph-traversal

I'm working with directed acyclic graphs in networkx. I have graphs that look like the figure below.
[image]

What I essentially want to do is remove all the nodes from this graph that are exclusively connected to paths with length less than 3. For example, in the graph above I would delete all the blue nodes and keep only the red ones.

What would be a best algorithm for this keeping in mind that these graphs can grow very large (upto 10K nodes)?

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306914/remove-all-nodes-in-a-binary-three-which-don-t-lie-in-any-path-with-sum-k) focuses on binary trees only and will not be applicable to my case. I'd prefer to achieve this on Python (networkx).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. generate the height map (a dictionary from node to height)
2. generate the inverse graph if needed (all edges are reversed)
3. generate the depth map (which is just the height map of the inverse graph)
4. nodes = [ n for n in nodes if hmap[n] + dmap[n] >= 3 ]

That's O(nodes+edges)